# Powershell Sharepoint Online - Adding a content type to a list

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, sharepoint-online

I'm trying to add a Content Type to a Document Library within Sharepoint Online.
My code below runs with no errors but the Content Type doesn't get added to the Document Library.

Any ideas?

Thanks
P

```
#Bind to site collection  
$Context = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($SiteURL)

#Get content types of the web
    $Context.Load($Context.Web.ContentTypes)
    $Context.ExecuteQuery()

    #Get the content type by its name
    $ContentType = $Context.Web.ContentTypes | Where {$_.Name -Match $newCT}
    $Context.Load($ContentType)   
    $Context.ExecuteQuery()

    #sharepoint online get content type id
    write-host -f Green "Content Type ID:" $ContentType.Id
    write-host -f Green "Content Type Title:" $ContentType.Name

    $List = $Context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle($DocLibName) 
    Write-host "List is " $DocLibName

    $Context.load($list)
    $Context.load($list.ContentTypes)
    $Context.ExecuteQuery()
    $list.ContentTypesEnabled=$true

    try{
        $addedContentType=$list.ContentTypes.AddExistingContentType($ContentType)
    }catch{
        write-host "ERROR!"
    }

    write-host -f Green "Added content type (" $newCT ") to list (" $DocLibName ")" 

    $list.Update()
``
```

Comment: Shouldn't you be doing `$addedContentType = $list.ContentTypes.Add($newCT); $list.Update()` instead of trying to find an existing contenttype?

Comment: Thanks @Theo I tried that but still the same. The code runs but it doesn't add the content type to the document library.

Comment: Apologies I am getting an error ... Cannot convert argument "parameters", with value: "Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ContentType", for "Add" to type "Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ContentTypeCreationInformation": "Cannot convert th
e "Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ContentType" value of type "Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ContentType" to type "Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ContentTypeCreationInformation"."

Comment: ```write-host "List name is " $list.Title
    write-host "List name is " $list.Id
    write-host "ContentType is " $ContentType.Name


    try{
        $addedContentType=$list.ContentTypes.Add($ContentType)
    }catch{
        write-host "ERROR!"
        Write-Host $_
    }

Comment: List name is  Test 1
List name is  38e48354-f82d-4e33-93e6-17864a0721a6
ContentType is  File Share Import 2
ERROR!
Cannot convert argument "parameters", with value: "Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ContentType", for "Add" to type "Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ContentTypeCreationInformation": "Cannot convert th
e "Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ContentType" value of type "Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ContentType" to type "Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ContentTypeCreationInformation"."
Added content type (  ) to list ( Test 1 )

Comment: Never liked Sharepoint.. The thing is, I don't see your code ever calling the `.Update()` method on the $list. What if you just add that to the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems I was missing this part ...

```
        $context.ExecuteQuery()
```